# Kotlin: How can I reduce child arrays into a single array?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a pice of code in Swift that reduces a list of `TVSchedule` objects into an array of `TVMatch` pobjects. Each TVSchedule, has a property called events, that is a list of `TVMatch`es.

The code in swift is the following:

```
var matches: [TVMatch] {
    let slots = timeSlots.reduce(into: [TVMatch]()) { (result, schedule) in
        result.append(contentsOf: schedule.events)
    }
    return slots
}
```

I'm trying to do the same reduce in Kotlin and the code I have is the following:

```
val matches: ArrayList<TVMatch>
    get() {
        val slots = timeSlots.fold(arrayListOf<TVMatch>()) { result, schedule ->
            result.addAll(schedule.events)
        }
        return slots
    }
```

However, the Kotlin code gives me a type error, and does not compile. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`addAll` returns a `boolean`, but the return value of the [`fold`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/fold.html)-operation should be of same type as the given initial object (in this case `ArrayList`).
You can solve that one easily by just adding `result` after your `addAll`-statement, e.g.:

```
result.addAll(schedule.events)
result // this is now the actual return value of the fold-operation
```

Alternatively just use [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html) or similar instead:

```
result.apply {
  addAll(schedule.events)
} // result is the return value then
```

Note that you can actually simplify altogether using [`flatMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html) to just (side-note: if you use this approach the `matches` are evaluated only once of course, but `flatMap` is the star here anyway ;-))):

```
val matches = timeSlots.flatMap { it.events } // this is a new list! (note, if you do several mappings in a row, you may want to use timeSlots.asSequence().flatMap { }.map { }.toList() / or .toMutableList() instead
```

Alternatively if you really require the `matches` to be of type `ArrayList`, use [`flatMapTo`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map-to.html) instead:

```
val matches = timeSlots.flatMapTo(ArrayList()) { it.events }
```

You can of course keep the `get()` if you must, or just move the getting of the matches to its own function, e.g.:

```
fun getMatches() = timeSlots.flatMapTo(ArrayList()) { it.events }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. With your detailed explanation it makes sense! I've ended up using FlatMap. I'll have to dig into the functional stuff a little bit more

Comment: you are welcome... and you probably already did: `reduce`/`fold` will come in handy in (a bit) more complex scenarios... now for your specific scenario `flatMap` suffices...

Answer (score 4):

Am I crazy, or can't you just replace the code with

```
val matches: List<TVMatch>
    get() = timeSlots.flatMap { schedule -> schedule.events }
```

?

Comment: You are correct, not crazy, and I thank you very much! I've accepted Roland's answer since it was more detailed.